# How to extract data based on csv file using Taleo Connect Client?

Tags: taleo, taleo-connect-client

We are doing an integration between a 3rd party application and our Taleo instance. We have a requirement where the 3rd party application will provide us a list of Candidates and we will import these Candidates in Taleo. No problem there. However, the 3rd party requires us to provide the Candidate Ids generated during the import process. I've been looking at the Export feature but couldn't find anything that allows me to filter based on a csv file.

Is there such a feature in Taleo Connect Client?

Answer (score 0):

I would Add a unique identifier to a Taleo UDF per import to stamp each candidate uploaded in each batch.

I would then Export candidates based on this stamp.